# avoid using size of a array c#

Tags: c#

I want to convert the above array to a list to avoid the declaration number of elements in the array but unable to achieve it because that is obvious that if i try to do the same thing on a list i will get a index out of bound exception.. have been trying through out the day. I pasted the part of the logic here where i am facing a problem.A recursive call in a being made to the function in the base class(This shouldn't matter to answer this question but just making it clear). 
please help me out.

```
    int[] arr = new int[100];        
    Dictionary<int, List<int>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();        

    public override int function(int length, out List<int> cuts)
    {
        cuts = new List<int>();
        if (length < 0)
            return 0;

        if (arr[length] == 0 )
        {
            arr[length] = base.Function(length, out cuts);
            dict.Add(arr[length], cuts);                                
        }
        cuts = dict[arr[length]];
        return arr[length];
    }
```

Comment: your code has many issues, for instance: `arr.[length]`

Comment: if an array and its length are interpreted in the normal manner, then `array [ length ]` is out of bounds (by definition of C#'s zero-based indexing for arrays).  What are we missing?

Comment: Sorry for that I correct them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just expand the list if the `length` (should be `index`) of the "dynamic grown" list is smaller than the index ("length" in your case).

```
List<int> arr = new List<int>();        
Dictionary<int, List<int>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();        

public override int function(int length, out List<int> cuts)
{
    cuts = new List<int>();
    if (length < 0)
        return 0;

    if (arr.Count <= length)
    {
        arr.AddRange(new int[(length + 1) - arr.Count])
    }

    if (arr[length] == 0 )
    {
        arr.Insert(length,base.Function(length, out cuts));
        dict.Add(arr[length], cuts);                                
    }
    cuts = dict[arr[length]];
    return arr[length];
}
```

Comment: this is recursive function so every time we do this the list is manipulated this should not happen.

Comment: who clears the list? (it is not made obvious in your question) and what list are you talking about `arr` or `cuts`?

Comment: Sorry i was talking about array

Comment: And Its wroking Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

***You can't create an array without a size. You'd need to use a list for that.***

If you don't have specific reason behind using Array, better you use [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx):

```
List<int> arr = new List<int>();
```

And at last you can convert it to Array also:

```
int[] s = arr.ToArray();
```

Comment: List[length] throws an error if i try to use a list because the index is not present. The value length varies randomly.

Comment: List<int> and arrays have indexes from 0 to (length-1).

Comment: Read the question again: "I want to convert the above array to a list"

Comment: You have to loop through using `for each` @user1301449